# Multi-Statement Template Plan Guide

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan, plan-guides

A piece of, um, software seems to be issuing ~20k queries of this form every few seconds:

```
DELETE FROM macVendor WHERE companyId=N'  08-00-'; INSERT INTO macVendor (companyId,organization) VALUES (N'  08-00-',N'TEKTRONIX INC.');
```

I don't know why, and no the values don't change...

Anyway, it really messes up the output of `dm_exec_cached_plans` so I figured I'd [create a plan guide to force parameterization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191275.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide @name = N'[PlanGuide-Stop-The-macVendorMadness]', 
    @stmt = N'DELETE FROM macVendor WHERE companyId=@0; INSERT INTO macVendor (companyId,organization) VALUES (@0,@1);',
    @type = N'TEMPLATE', 
    @params = N'@0 nvarchar(4000),@1 nvarchar(4000)' ,
    @hints = N'OPTION(PARAMETERIZATION FORCED)'
```

It seems however that plan guides can't be created for multiple statements?

```
Msg 10506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create plan guide 'PlanGuide-Stop-The-macVendorMadness' because parameter @stmt has more than one statement.
```

Any hints/help would be much appreciated!

---

Update: I've created 2 plan guides (DELETE/INSERT) and they *were* used but only ~17k times (each) out of the 110k executions.

Comment: You have two statements there. You need to create a plan guide for each statement (though I'm not sure one will be necessary for the insert, on the other hand I don't know what "messes up" means). And you also need to go back to the vendor of the software and give them the 'ol WTF.

Comment: I tried two separate plans, but they didn't seem to be used.

Messes up = 22k cached query plans just moments after `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`.

Comment: This is the table and query I'm using http://pastebin.com/K0Cd9Erq - I'm not sure the best place to put the output?